# MySql finding number of rows greater than or lesser than value

Tags: mysql, sql, math

I am trying to find a percentile rank using this formula.`(B+0.5E)*100/(N)` for 'X'. where x is the value what i have in 'emp' table.B=number of values below x, E=number of values equal to x , and N =total number of values in that table.
i am having difficulties in finding 'B' AND 'E' in MySQL.. i have already tried with query but its not working..is it possible to make run a single query for whole formula?

Comment: I think that I have a similar situation in one of my programs where each examinee's result is ranked as a percentile of all the results. I precalculate the percentile by iterating over all the results and creating a table showing that (for example) 1% received a mark equal or less than 1, 2% a mark equal or less than 2, 5% a mark equal or less than 3, etc. Once you have precalculated the percentiles, locating all values (users, examinees) with a percentile less than a given value becomes trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace B by :

```
SUM(IF(column_of_value < 'x', column_of_value, 0))
```

and E by :

```
 SUM(IF(column_of_value = 'x', column_of_value, 0))
```

and N by :

```
 COUNT(column_of_value)
```

Your calculation becomes :

```
((SUM(IF(column_of_value < 'x', column_of_value, 0)) + (0.5 * SUM(IF(column_of_value = 'x', column_of_value, 0)))) * 100) / COUNT(column_of_value) AS result
```

## See [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21bf9/5) here.

Comment: I think you had it right with the `if(col<x,1,0)`? I thought it was about counts rather than sums of the actual marks.

Comment: I am +1'ing this answer, but I think that the OP is actually after: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21bf9/5 (Fork on your fiddle - the 5 is given a 50% rank as it should as it it is the exact middle of the data)

Comment: You're absolutely right! N = total number of values not its sum. I'll correct my answer.

Comment: I don't want to nitpick, but I did also change `SUM(IF(column_of_value < 'x', column_of_value, 0))` to `SUM(IF(column_of_value < 'x', 1, 0))` in the fork I made, B and E still need to be counts rather than sums - which you neatly did with the original answer you posted.

Comment: thanks alot Ninsuo and  Fluffeh...for fixing this problem.... but i want to know one thing , whi=y have used `column_of_value < 'x', 1, 0` whats that 1,0 ???

Comment: That's a mistake : I am used to use SUM(IF( to count several columns in several conditions in a single request, so I naturally put 1, 0 instead of your value. Example `SUM(IF(error_status = 'ERROR', 1, 0)) as actions_in_error, SUM(IF(error_status = 'WAITING', 1, 0) as pending_actions, ...`

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry if this isn't guiding you in the right direction, but I am having difficulty understanding your question. Would something like this help you:

```
select
    emp,
    (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            tableName
        where
            emp=a.emp
    ) as E,
    (
        select
            count(*)
        from
            tableName
        where
            emp<a.emp
    ) as B,
    (
        select
            count(*)
        from 
            tableName
    ) as N
from
    tableName a
```

It is making a series of subselects that return the values you want for your formula.

Edit: I totally missed the mysql in the heading (have added the tag to the question).

@Ninsuo is on the right track with mysql supporting a handy `if` statement which you can use - though I think you need to use counts of records rather than their aggregate sum.

Something like this should get you in the right path:

```
select
    emp,
    (SUM(IF(column_of_value < emp, 1, 0)) +0.5*SUM(IF(column_of_value = emp, 1, 0)))*100/count(emp) as percentile
from 
    yourTableName
group by
    emp
```

Comment: thanks for answering Fluffeh.... in your answer you have splited the solution... but iam looking for one query that can give a result using that formula i have specified...